# In LLVM LOOP PASS, I want to copy and paste a set of Instructions. error occurs when copy icmp and branch instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

Below is my code in LLVM LoopPass.

```
virtual bool runOnLoop(Loop* L, LPPassManager &LPM) {
    BasicBlock& loopCondBlock = *(L->getHeader());
    BasicBlock& loopIncBlock = *(L->getLoopLatch());
    BranchInst* brInsInLoopInc = dyn_cast<BranchInst>(loopIncBlock.getTerminator());
    for (auto &inst: loopCondBlock) {
        auto *new_inst = inst.clone();
        new_inst->insertBefore(brInsInLoopInc);
        llvm::ValueToValueMapTy vmap;
        llvm::RemapInstruction(new_inst, vmap, RF_NoModuleLevelChanges | RF_IgnoreMissingLocals);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want to copy instructions in for.cond and paste them on for.inc before branch back to for.cond instruction.

Example original IR:

```
for.cond:                                         ; preds = %for.inc, %entry
  %0 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %cmp = icmp ult i32 %0, 50000000
  br i1 %cmp, label %for.body, label %for.end

for.body:                                         ; preds = %for.cond
  ...

for.inc:                                          ; preds = %for.body
  ...
  br label %for.cond
```

IR Expected:

```
for.cond:                                         ; preds = %for.inc, %entry
  %0 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %cmp = icmp ult i32 %0, 50000000
  br i1 %cmp, label %for.body, label %for.end

for.body:                                         ; preds = %for.cond
  ...

for.inc:                                          ; preds = %for.body
  ...
  // ******PASS ADDED******
  %4 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %cmp2 = icmp ult i32 %4, 50000000
  br i1 %cmp2, label %for.body, label %for.end
  // ******PASS ADDED******
```

My Loop Pass Result:

```
for.cond:                                         ; preds = %for.inc, %entry
  %0 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %cmp = icmp ult i32 %0, 50000000
  br i1 %cmp, label %for.body, label %for.end

for.body:                                         ; preds = %for.inc, %for.cond
  ...

for.inc:                                          ; preds = %for.body
  ...
  // ******PASS ADDED******
  %4 = load i32, i32* %i, align 4
  %5 = icmp ult i32 %0, 50000000
  br i1 %cmp, label %for.body, label %for.end
  // ******PASS ADDED******
  br label %for.cond
```

How to fix the icmp and related branch instruction to be correct and remove the "br label %for.cond"?

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to actually fill the value to value map used in the remap call with mappings from original to copy.

According to [the manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#deleting-instructions), deleting instructions should work by calling `eraseFromParent`.

This code is untested, so it will likely contain errors, but it should convey the idea:

```
virtual bool runOnLoop(Loop* L, LPPassManager &LPM) {
    BasicBlock& loopCondBlock = *(L->getHeader());
    BasicBlock& loopIncBlock = *(L->getLoopLatch());
   BranchInst* brInsInLoopInc = dyn_cast<BranchInst>(loopIncBlock.getTerminator());
    llvm::ValueToValueMapTy vmap;
    for (auto &inst: loopCondBlock) {
        auto *new_inst = inst.clone();
        new_inst->insertBefore(brInsInLoopInc);
        // map each instruction to its copy
        vmap[&inst] = new_inst;
        // now this should remap each instruction to its copy
        llvm::RemapInstruction(new_inst, vmap, RF_NoModuleLevelChanges | RF_IgnoreMissingLocals);
    }
    // now erase the original branch
    brInsInLoopInc->eraseFromParent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I have seen this on the other post, but it makes more errors on this line "vmap[inst] = newInst; ".

Comment: See the edit, I forgot an "&". I could have fixed this much earlier if you had posted the error message :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But It also generates wrong IR like:
"%5 = icmp ult i32 %0, 50000000" and "br i1 %5, label %for.body, label %for.end". It should use %cmp for correct.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Could you make your example compileable so this can be debugged?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my question just add below code after "inst.clone();".

```
if(inst.hasName()) {
    new_inst->setName(inst.getName()+NameSuffix);
}
```